# How can I fasten baseboard over concrete?

Tags: drywall, concrete, plywood

I have a concrete curb of about 6" from subfloor to the plate in the room that I plan to finish with 5/8 drywall.  I am figuring the best way to attach drywall and baseboard over it. One option would be to waterproof concrete with RedGard and then glue drywall to it and then follow with gluing baseboard.
Other approach, that I favor, is to attach 5/8 pressure treated plywood to concrete with tapcons and have 5/8 drywall above it. Then I can use 1" nails to attach baseboard to the plywood.
Will something like this work? Any other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either could work.

I've also used trim-head screws in plastic plugs for base trim over concrete. That would involve pre-drilling to mark screw location, then drilling the concrete and installing the plugs, then screwing on the trim. The holes would be larger, but that's mostly a problem if you're using stained trim.

Of course you could fur out the wall to create a more standard backing situation. You'd lose 1-1/2" of room space.